# Change constraint hooking from one view to another - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

**Explanation**

assuming a ViewController contains View1 and View2 that are hooked to each other by a constraint, and i want to add another view lets say View3 between these two views. What is the best way to update the constraint?
to reach that View1 and View3 are hooked, and View3 and View2 are hooked.

**Pictures**

[image]
[image]

---

I know i could achieve this by setting up the height of View3 to 0 and then update its height in the code.

**Question:**

Is it heavy on the memory to add empty UIViews in the ViewController or is it best to create these views programmatically whenever needed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a few static views I think it's perfectly fine to use the option you mentioned. If you are strict in memory usage, you can just use an empty view which height you set to 0, then when you need to show the view you can start loading the view and add it to the empty view after setting the empty view's height to the view you just created.

If you can ignore iOS8 and below, you might want to check out [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html)

Alternatively depending on your layout you might be able to use UICollectionView / UITableView to lay your views / buttons or update your constraints programmatically